# Echo steam avatar and steam name in php & html code without login

Tags: php, html, api, steam

I want to make a code who echo a users name and his avatar from steam, but i dont know how, i tryied this: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=52A66B13219F645834149F1A1180770A&steamids=76561197960435530 but i dont know how to get just the username and the avatar from that info im getting, any help?

Comment: In future, you should read through the API's documentation and at least come up with a partially working solution / attempt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must get the content of this file through [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) and parse that json format to php array. After just get element `personaname` and `avatar` and use it with your HTML code

Comment: Im getting this: http://vanityrp.site.nfoservers.com/apply/test.php

Comment: $steam = json_decode($steamjson);
echo $steam->response->players->avatar;

Comment: ^^ Players is an array, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

An example of how you could parse that json.

```
$json = file_get_contents('http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamUser/GetPlayerSummaries/v0002/?key=52A66B13219F645834149F1A1180770A&steamids=76561197960435530');
$parsed = json_decode($json);

foreach($parsed->response->players as $player){
    echo $player->personaname . '<br>';
    echo "<img src='" . $player->avatar . "'>";
}
```

If you have any questions, feel free to ask!